# Target nested class in .each loop and exclude $currentContainer with :not

Tags: jquery, each

Im running an .each to target content in a specific class and excluding this class in a certain container with `div:not(#container2)`

My issue is that when the targeted .class is nested deep inside of `#container2` then I can't target it like so:

```
var currentActiveDiv = $("#container2");

$('div:not(#container2) .hello').each(function(index){
    $(this).html("bye");
})
```

The .hello class would be nested even deeper than in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/3/

Comment: Its' not working in the fiddle atleast? Container 2 should print out "hello"

Comment: It's because `div` matches all the divs

Comment: You want to find the target class, then traverse the dom to check it's parent.  Answer provided.

Comment: You can just be more specific and do `$('div[id^=container]:not(#container2) .hello')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/5/

Comment: This would assume all main containers is named something with "container" right? the real case actually have totally different container names

Comment: Then you should add a common class, to target them easier.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick... but assumes that target div will be nested at the same level for each occurence.

```
$('.hello').each(function(index){
    var parentid = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').prop('id');
    if (parentid != "container2"){
        $(this).html("bye");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @adeneo , `$('div:not(#container2) .hello')` selects all `div` elements ; try selecting only `div` elements where `id` begins with "container" then adding `:not()` to selector

```
// alternatively `$('[id^=container][id!=container2]')`
$('div[id^=container]:not(#container2) .hello').each(function(index){
    $(this).html("bye");
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/6/